# Change All DropDowns in DetailTable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

Using Telerik ASP.NET MVC library. So have a Grid with a DetailTemplate that is a child grid. In the detail grid every row has a Telerik DropDownList.  The parent table row also has a DropDownList.

The requirement is if the parent dropdownlist gets changed then all of the detail row dropdownlists should be changed to same selected item. If the detail row gets changed then the parent dropdownlist should be changed to an item that is "Multiple" if the detail all dont have the same value. If the all the detail have the same value then the parent should be changed to that value.

Parent Row - DropDownList Selected Value - "Default"
Detail Rows - DropDownList Selected Values are all different.
Change Parent Row - DropDownList Selected Value to "Detailed"
All Details Rows - DropDownList Value get changed to "Detailed"

I have been able to change the datasource of all the Detail Table rows. That doesnt cause the DropDownList to change the selected value.

Dont know how to traverse from the parent to the detail rows and select the dropdownlist in the row and then change the selected value.